# Would this be considered a Well formed formula?

Tags: logic

In logic, is this a well formed formula?

> $(\exists p, \forall q$ $\phi)$ where $\phi$ is a formula?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if $\phi$ is a formula, then $\forall q \ \phi$ is a formula as well (assuming $q$ is a variable), and therefore $\exists p \forall q \ \phi$ is a formula as well (assuming $p$ is a variable).